# Problem with workflow REST

Tags: workflow, rest, api

I seem to be having a problem making a rest call to create a list or add a user to a SharePoint group. Both give me the same error -

```
Response: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified."}}}
```

I've followed a few different guides and googled the issue, but cant resolve it.
Interestingly I have a workflow using REST that creates a sharepoint site ok.

this is what I am following - http://codelesssharepointinfopath.com/workflow-useful-rest-calls-add-user-to-group/

Here is my workflow -

[image]

The workflow emails me all the dictionaries/variables that are used -

```
URL: http://abc.abc.com/_api/web/sitegroups/GetByName('trainees')/users

Meta: {"Type":"SP.User"}

Params: {"__metadata":{"Type":"SP.User"},"LoginName":"i:0#.w|abc\\nick"}

Request Header: {"Accept":"application\/json;odata=verbose","Content-Type":"application\/json;odata=verbose"}

Response Code: BadRequest

Response: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified."}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of a minor typo in the post data. The "t" in the "type" object property should be lower case:

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.User"},"LoginName":"i:0#.w|abc\\nick"}
```